# how and when to call a react component methods after state change from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In a single react component a user clicks a button => which calls a method => triggers an action => async fetch => reducer updates state => component receives new props.

back in the original component that triggered the action I have been using:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.someProp !== this.props.someProp){
        //ok new prop is here
        this.someMethod(nextProps.someProp);
    }
}
```

Am I going about this in the right way?

It just seems somewhat clunky and detached as a callback mechanism from the user action or change of state. It just makes following the logical flow of the component harder once there are a few of these, I have a component with 3 of these and already think it's not as easy to reason about especially when they are part of a related flow a > b > c . And I have ended up with this kind of thing:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    if(this.patchJavaScriptWillLoad(nextProps)){
        this.createPatchInstance();
        // method fires an action which will also result in state change that triggers the below.
    }

    if(this.patchInstanceWillBeReady(nextProps)){
        this.startPatchAudio(nextProps.webAudioPatch.instance);
        // method fires an action which will also result in state change that triggers the below.
    }

    if(this.patchParametersWillChange(nextProps)){
        this.updateWebAudioPatchParameters(nextProps.webAudioPatchParameters);
    }
}

// abstracted away if conditions to make componentWillReceiveProps more readable.
```

But is this how it should be done or is this a symptom of not moving enough logic to action creators?

Comment: Not knowing the specifics of your functions it would be hard to judge, but it does feel that your callback logic can be moved to action creators, especially if you're using redux-thunk.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is getting deprecated. Look up getDerivedStateFromProps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More detailed examples would be useful, but based on what you have here, I think I see what you're getting at.

Short answer: Yes, this is a symptom of not moving enough logic to the action creators.  Ideally, your component should be a pure view component. No need for `componentWillReceiveProps` in most cases - you simply render whatever the props are and that's that. This is why Abramov (creator of redux) argues for functional components. More on that [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html).

If you need to perform other actions after an async call returns with some data, you would do that, as you said, in the action creator.  I'm going to go with an example that uses thunks:

**EDIT:** I added an example of the component passing a reference to the audio player as an argument to the action. That way, the action can manipulate after the async step.

```
//An async action creator that uses the thunk pattern.
//You could call this method from your component just like any other
//action creator.

export function getMaDatums(audioPlayer, audioContext) {
  return function (dispatch) {

    //make the actual call to get the data
    return fetch(`http://<your stuff here>`)
      .then(data => {

        //call dispatch again to do stuff with the data
        dispatch(gotDataAction(data));

        //call dispatch some more to take further actions
        dispatch(...);

        //since the component passed us references to these, we can
        //interact with them here, after our data has loaded! FTW!
        audioPlayer.doTheThings();
        audioSession.doTheOtherThings();

        //plus anything else you want...
      });
  }
}
```

If you want to learn more about the doing async stuff with redux, or for that matter, interfacing with stateful libraries from your redux app, I highly recommend giving the redux documentation a good read. The basis of the thunk example above came from [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).

Good luck and have fun with React + Redux!

Comment: @Ian thanks, yes I am already using redux-thunk, I guess the issue is that the component needs to communicate with the dom api in between actions. In my case this is using the web audio api which is tied to a dom Audio element within the component. And I then need to be able to pass the Audio Context around as a singleton. I can understand the argument for functional components in presentational components but I'm not sure how to achieve this in higher order components / smart / containers.

Comment: @njorlsaga In that case, I would consider passing a reference to your audio player as an argument to the action.  As far as passing the audio context around as a singleton, you might be able to design around that if you pass it to the appropriate actions as an argument as well.  I edited the answer to demonstrate - does that help you at all?

Comment: @Ian, thanks, yeah the tricky thing is though that the audio context needs to be kept somewhere as a reference as it is called by other things at different times (disconnect - reconnect, sources etc..), currently I am storing it in redux state but it feels kinda dirty as I'm sure the reference is not immutable. But thanks for your help it confirmed some of my suspicions, hopefully I can refactor some of the calls inside componentWillReceiveProps out to an action creator.

Comment: @njorlsaga: Happy to help and glad this has been useful to you.  Maybe you could have a startup action that passed the audio context in the action, and then have a middleware that listens for that action and saves a local reference to the context. Then the middleware could listen for other actions (coming from anywhere in the app) and perform the necessary manipulations to the context.  That way you get the audio context out of state tree, and still have a single reference for it.

Comment: @Ian ah that is interesting I have not written any middleware yet and not thought about that, only used 3rd party like redux-thunk I will check that out. I need to do some more research in this area as to what the convention is to store references or interface with these kind of instances like navigator.getUserMedia etc.  in the react-redux ecosystem .

Answer (score 11):

Coming back to my own question years later now.

If I can use a functional component, I would use the react hook useEffect. If the logic can be externalised then perhaps in a saga.

```
useEffect(() => {
  methodToCallIfPropChanges()
}, [watchedProp]);
```

Comment: This causing component to render twice,  testing keep failing at this expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(1), it keep calling twice, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

An update can be caused by changes to props or state. These methods are called in the following order when a component is being re-rendered:

- static getDerivedStateFromProps()
- shouldComponentUpdate()
- render()
- getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()
- **componentDidUpdate()**
  Try to use **componentDidUpdate()**

React docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating